warning: discards 'const' qualifiers from pointer target type (const struct)
I got a structure:
typedef struct { double T;    double P;      double ro;       double a;       }atmosphere;
And how i define it:
const atmosphere atm_knots[atm_size] = { ... }
One more const double:
const double atm_h_knots[atm_size] = { ... }
Next i got a function:
double lin_int_for_struct(int X_size, int Line_size, int element_offset, double* X, double* Y, double x)
And when im trying to do next one:
temp   = lin_int_for_struct(atm_size, 4, 0, &atm_h_knots[0], &atm_knots[0].T, h)
It gives me a warning:
passing argument 4 of 'lin_int_for_struct' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
Can someone help how to fix it?

This is tagged at C#, but the code is not C#. Did you mean to tag it as C/C++?

The problem, of course, is that your arrays are const -- you're not allowed to change the elements. However, the pointers passed to lin_int_for_struct are not const -- it's allowed to do *X = 3 or *Y = 4. But you're passing a pointer into your const array.
